How to change the value of a repository Flow?
I came across this article:
https://proandroiddev.com/loading-initial-data-in-launchedeffect-vs-viewmodel-f1747c20ce62
In this article, the author, while describing the advantages and disadvantages of different data initialization approaches, concludes that it's best to do it using StateFlow. I decided to give it a try, considering that I use the UiState wrapper as a common state for the screen and MyRepo as the data source:
sealed class UiState<out T> {
    object Loading : UiState<Nothing>()
    data class Error(val code: Int? = null, val message: String? = null) : UiState<Nothing>()
    data class Content<T>(val data: T) : UiState<T>()
}

class MyRepo {
    fun getMyData(): Flow<List<String>> {
        return flow {
            delay(1000)
            emit(listOf("1", "2"))
        }
    }
}

This is my implementation before the changes:
class MyViewModel1(repo: MyRepo) : ViewModel() {
    data class ScreenStateUI(
        val data: List<String> = emptyList(),
        val title: String = "Title",
    )

    private val _screenUiState: MutableStateFlow<UiState<ScreenStateUI>> =
        MutableStateFlow(UiState.Loading)
    val screenUiState: StateFlow<UiState<ScreenStateUI>> = _screenUiState.asStateFlow()

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repo.getMyData()
                .map<List<String>, UiState<ScreenStateUI>> { UiState.Content(ScreenStateUI(data = it)) }
                .collectLatest {
                    if (it is UiState.Content) {
                        _screenUiState.emit(it)
                    }
                }
        }
    }

    fun updateTitle(title: String) {
        _screenUiState.update {
            if (it is UiState.Content) {
                it.copy(data = it.data.copy(title = title))
            } else {
                it
            }
        }
    }
}

During initialization, the state is loaded, and the UI can subscribe to changes via screenUiState. This means there are no issues if you need to use fun updateTitle(title: String).
Now I’ve changed the implementation to remove the initialization in the init block and make everything happen as soon as the UI subscribes to the event:
class MyViewModel2(repo: MyRepo) : ViewModel() {
    data class ScreenStateUI(
        val data: List<String> = emptyList(),
        val title: String = "Title",
    )

    val screenUiState: StateFlow<UiState<ScreenStateUI>> by lazy {
        repo.getMyData()
            .map<List<String>, UiState<ScreenStateUI>> { UiState.Content(ScreenStateUI(data = it)) }
            .onStart { emit(UiState.Loading) }
            .catch { emit(UiState.Error(message = it.message)) }
            .stateIn(
                scope = viewModelScope,
                started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000),
                initialValue = UiState.Loading,
            )
    }

    fun updateTitle(title: String) {
        ...
    }
}

So, everything seems to look fine, and indeed, the UI now triggers requests only when it subscribes. However, the state can no longer be updated, and consequently, the function updateTitle cannot update the title anymore.
What am I missing here?

Is there any UI component that calls val screenUiState?
Otherwise there entire logic won't be triggered

@smoothBlue yep, sure there is. Just wanted to keep it simple, but yep, there is definitely a subscriber.

You have two sources of data. The repository provides the list, the title is stored in the view model.
What you are missing is the storage for the title. Just add another MutableStateFlow that holds the title. It can be changed as usual and it can also be incorporated into your chain of flow operations:
class MyViewModel2(repo: MyRepo) : ViewModel() {
    data class ScreenStateUI(
        val data: List<String>,
        val title: String,
    )

    private val titleFlow = MutableStateFlow("Title")

    val screenUiState: StateFlow<UiState<ScreenStateUI>> by lazy {
        combine(
            repo.getMyData(),
            titleFlow,
        ) { data, title ->
            UiState.Content<ScreenStateUI>(ScreenStateUI(data = data, title = title))
        }
            .onStart<UiState<ScreenStateUI>> { emit(UiState.Loading) }
            .catch<UiState<ScreenStateUI>> { emit(UiState.Error(message = it.message)) }
            .stateIn<UiState<ScreenStateUI>>(
                scope = viewModelScope,
                started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000),
                initialValue = UiState.Loading,
            )
    }

    fun updateTitle(title: String) {
        titleFlow.value = title
    }
}

combine takes multiple flows as input and merges their content. This is why titleFlow needs to be a flow, otherwise screenUiState cannot be updated with the title.
If, later on, you decide to store the title somewhere else (outside of the view model, in a database for example), you just need to replace titleFlow with the flow from that new data source and change updateTitle to call that data source's update method accordingly.

seems like it makes sense, however, I am not sure, about if I call - updateTitle(title, likely combine will trigger repo.getMyData() again, instead of reuse what it already has in the state, like we do for example with titleFlow.update {} when it updates only field that is necessary. Does that make sense?

combine is only executed a single time, when the screenUiState property is first accessed and the lazy lambda is executed. And only then repo.getMyData() is executed. The lambda of combine, however, is executed multiple times, whenever any of the two flows emits a new value. Conclusion: The flows are only ever accessed once.
